# Xcode 9 Jump to definition in a new tab, window, or other navigation area with Option-Shift-Command+Click

Tags: xcode, shortcut

Xcode 9 seems to be missing jump to definition shortcut Option-Shift-Command+Click. You used to be able to use to open definition in a new tab, window, or other navigation areas with Option-Shift-Command+Click. In Xcode 9 this still works from the file navigator but not when you use this on a class. Has anyone been able to figure out how to use this shortcut in xcode 9?

Comment: What code have you tried?  What do you mean by not working?  Is it not navigating, do you get an error message, are the classes/methods not available?

Answer (score 26):

You can use Xcode preferences to personalise the double click and the action selector.

From this window you can change CMD + click to open the definition instead of the action selector (as it was in Xcode 8)

you can also change the behaviour of optional navigation, so that it opens a tab

By setting the configuration as shown below, you can CMD + ALT + click to jump to definition in a new tab.

This also restores Option-Shift-Command+Click to show the window selector as you wanted

[image: Xcode]

Comment: This is all on the "Navigation" tab, in case that wasn't too obvious :)

Answer (score 12):

Marco's screenshot was helpful.

The keyboard commands for Xcode 9 have changed:

#### Jump to Definition

- Same window : **Command-Control-click** (was Command-double-click)
- In assistant pane : **Command-Option-Control-click**
- In separate window/pane : **Command-Option-Control-Shift-click**

#### Quick Help

- **Option-click** (same as Xcode 8)

Answer (score 4):

As soon as I asked a question I found a solution by accident.

1. Command + click on the class to bring up the new action selector
2. Shift + Alt + Click to chose where to open (tab, new window, etc)

Alternatively, can use Command + Option + Control + Shift to do this all at once but I'm not sure how convenient that is

Answer (score -1):

First, Open the file.

Then:

- New Window : `Cmd` + `Shift` + `t`
- The Assistance Editor : `Cmd` + `t`